# Array of integer pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pass-by-reference, swap

I am trying to implement quick sort and trying to manipulate the array that has to be sorted, but the ff is giving me a totally different behavior so was wondering how different they could be.
Say I have a base integer pointer (the array that has to be sorted):

```
void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int *base_array;
int left;
int right;

//So how does the ff(following) differ?
swap(&base_array[left], &base_array[right])
//swap(base_array + left, base_array + right)
```

The first call of swap is giving me a weird output(array is not sorted properly) while the second does seem to do well but I don't really know how different they are?

Comment: Please try to create a proper [mre] to show us. And what do you mean with "ff"?

Comment: Though it might help if you learn that for any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `p[i]` is *exactly* equal to `*(p + i)`. From that follows that `&p[i]` is the same as `p + i`.

Comment: The first is a dereference of both parameters. The second is "pointer arithmetic" of both parameters... That's the difference....

Answer (score 1):

You are not matching the `swap` function prototype since you are passing `int` instead of `int *`:

```
swap(&base_array[left], &base_array[right])
swap(base_array + left, base_array + right)
```

If you are using GCC then you can catch this kind of mistake by enabling the `-Wall` compiler flag. And even better, enabling this flag `-Werror` will treat all warnings as errors... This last one is a bit severe, but ensures quality :)

Comment: `-Wall -Werror` is definitely a good idea. Don't we all wish it were the default setting for beginners and more savvy programmers too?

Comment: @chqrlie Definitely!

Answer (score 0):

The first call `swap(base_array[left], base_array[right])` passes `int` values to `swap` which expects `int` pointers. The behavior is undefined, quite possibly a program termination. The *weird* output is a compiler warning: do not ignore these, they always indicate some kind of problem in the code that should be addressed.

The second call `swap(base_array + left, base_array + right)` is OK: it passes pointers and is equivalent to:

```
    swap(&base_array[left], &base_array[right])
```

Note the difference between `base_array[left]` which evaluates to the array element at index `left` and `&base_array[left]` which evaluates to the **address** of this element, ie: a pointer to it.

By the way, the question title is misleading: `base_array` is not an array of integer pointers, it is an array of `int`, the `swap()` function receives pointers to two array elements.

Answer (score 0):

In this function call

```
swap(base_array + left, base_array + right);
```

you re passing elements of the array by reference through pointers to them. So the function works correctly. It indeed expects pointers to the elements of the array that must be swapped.

This function call

```
swap(base_array[left], base_array[right])
```

is equivalent to the following

```
swap( *(base_array + left ), *( base_array + right ) );
```

That is you are not passing elements of the array by reference through a pointers to them by are passing the elements themselves of the type `int`. It means that the function will have undefined behavior because it will consider values of the elements as addresses

```
void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```